# Using zcat and sed in find -exec

Tags: bash, sed, find, zcat

I need to create a big text file using the contents of several gzipped files with a specific name pattern. To do that I used:

```
find . -name '*dna.toplevel.txt.gz' -exec zcat {} >> all.txt \;
```

and it worked just fine. The problem is, now I need to edit the text on the fly to substitute a specific character ">" with ">filename|". I've managed to cook this up:

```
find . -name '*dna.toplevel.txt.gz' -exec zcat {} | sed 's/>/>{}|/g' >> all.txt \;
```

But I am getting the following errors:

- sed: can't read ;: No such file or directory
- find: missing argument to `-exec'

I understand poor bash is confused because I did not specify correctly where each command ends, but I have no idea how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-exec` takes a simple command and its arguments; it does not handle shell constructs like pipes or redirections at all. Your original command is identical to

```
find . -name '*dna.toplevel.txt.gz' -exec zcat {} \; >> all.txt
```

since the shell recognizes the output redirection immediately and removes it from the command line before identifying the command (`find`) and its arguments.

Since `sed` requires the filename from `find` as part of its command, you'll need to run a shell that takes the pipeline as an argument via the `-c` option.

```
find . -name '*dna.toplevel.txt.gz' -exec \
  sh -c "zcat {} | sed 's/>/>{}|/g'" \; >> all.txt
```

There are a few problems with this approach; fixing them requires making the `sh` command quite a bit more complicated. If you are using `bash` 4 or later, I'd recommend ditching `find` altogether and using a shell loop along with the `**` glob:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*dna.toplevel.txt.gz; do
    zcat "$f" | sed "s|>|>$f|g"
done >> all.txt
```

If this command is creating `all.txt`, you can simply use `>` instead of `>>`. This also assumes that `$f` won't contain any `|` characters; if it does, you'll need to choose a different delimiter.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try putting quotes (`"`) around the argument to `-exec`.</s>

```
find . -name '*dna.toplevel.txt.gz' -exec "zcat {} | sed 's/>/>{}|/g'" >> all.txt \;
```

You need to escape the pipeline:

```
find . -name '*dna.toplevel.txt.gz' -exec zcat {} \| sed 's/>/>{}|/g' >> all.txt \;
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this caused the following errors instead: `bash: /: Is a directory`
`find: missing argument to \`-exec'`